# How to merge two shapes from KML files and get coordinates of overlapped area?

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

There are two KML/KMZ files. As an example one of them has coordinates of black square and another one has coordinates of green square. How can I get coordinates of red square (which is overlapped area)? Looks like ideally this can be scripted or generated using program.

If this can be achieved, then to summarise the goal is to analyse and merge two KML/KMZ files of boundaries and create smaller shapes in one KML/KMZ.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: What OS do you use? Does each KML file have just one shape in it? Please provide sample files.

Comment: Mac OS, Linux or Windows is fine. The KML files contain multiple shapes. For an example how to split shapes into smaller ones based on these two: [KML1](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1eIjWEQyO-PchgJUttxBBkYqvPxE&ll=51.5117432899754%2C-0.1284054999998716&z=12) [KML2](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1KE3Tlm1Bhe4ZbE5bzhD69BZb7Js&hl=en_US&ll=51.625809999999994%2C-0.1537230000000136&z=10)

Comment: Hello, @laimison I am fetching the same problem in my case I have only one kml / kmz file . Did you guys solve the problem

Comment: hi @sujanmaharjan unfortunately, no. The plan has changed. That's interesting, but I might need it some day. I would like to skip learning QGIS and use suggested/possible approaches in Python so that task can be automated. Some guys convert kml to GeoJSON https://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/ . So you can look for possibilities from this format too. Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use software that can perform basic GIS analysis functions. A good free option is QGIS.  Load your KML files and then go to the Vector menu and find the Intersect tool.

If you need commandline/script/programatic options, you can look into GDAL and it's OGR Intersection method.